# GWT : getting InvocationTargetException while making a server call

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, gwt-rpc

On submit of login form I make an async call once I find that the user is valid I want to redirect him to a servlet which serves html content..
While trying to do so I am facing InvocationTargetException.
Following is the code snippet

```
@Override
public Boolean validateUser(String emailId, String password){

//validate the user

if(valid){

HttpServletResponseWrapper wrapper =injector.getInstance(HttpServletResponseWrapper.class);

wrapper.setResponse(response);

wrapper.sendRedirect("/render?viewPage=" + PageNameConstant.LANDINGPAGE);
}                   
}
```

In the RenderServlet

```
ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = servletResponse.getOutputStream();

 servletOutputStream.write(pgContent.getBytes());

 **servletOutputStream.close();**
```

I get the exception when I try to close the servletOutputStream.

how should I go about doing the above?

Comment: You should provide all the details, like how you make the request, what servlet or handler is supposed to handle it, and the error log.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have added some code snippets of my implementation any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

That is not `Target invocation exception`  it's `InvocationTargetException`

That `request` cannot be complete because of

```
1)If it is live server,Client network disconnected . 

2)Or if you are compiled your `impl` classes using java 1.7.
```

Switch back to java 6 and try. GWT not supporting java 7 as of now.

I'm suspecting you compiled with 1.7. no ?

Comment: @Suresh Atta I am using jdk_1.6 for compilation, as of now I am testing the implementation in hosted mode..